# Using Mercurial to maintain two versions of a program - clone or named branches?

Tags: mercurial, branch

We are using Mercurial to manage a project, but we now want to create a "Lite" version of the same project (ie a version with some of the functionality removed or simplified).

Since the Lite version will share most of its code with the Full version, we are considering whether it is better to either:

1. Create a clone of the original project and keep each project separate.
2. Use named branches to maintain both versions of the project within the same repository.

We are fairly new to version control software and this will be the first time that we have used named branches.  Can someone please help outline the pros and cons of each approach.  Which approach would make it easiest to maintain bug fixes between the two projects?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Have you considered making the distinction between the full and the lite version part of the build process instead of maintaining two separate versions?

Comment: The app in question is a web app, so there is no build process as such.

Comment: Deployment process then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of **4 methods** - they have more or less the same amount of functionality and differ only in used commands for syncing codebase

For "Separate clones" solution "...keep each project separate" is Bad Thing (tm) and violation of DRY principle: re-used code (Lite version) must be maintained in single place and changes in core pulled from Lite repo to Full repo

**Note**:

When I wrote about 4 solutions, I had in mind, except clones and named branches also

- MQ (Lite version is changesets in repository, Full version is MQ-patch(es) on top of Lie in the same repo
- Subrepositories|Guestrepo (Lite version is superrepo, Full version functionality is one or more subrepositories in superrepository)

Comment: Maybe sum up which 4 methods you are referring to specifically? Cause right now it looks as if you’re recommending MQ, whereas I’d say there are more preferable options.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as the intended use case for either MQ or subrepositories. Mercurial queues are linear and somewhat transient; using subrepositories assumes that you can completely factor out a feature set into its own set of files; this can work for a library with a well-defined public API, but would be very difficult to achieve for two versions of the same application.

Comment: @LaurensHolst - yes, in common case I'll prefer (and use) MQ in order to maintain fork'ed project in sync with upstream: it's just *another headache*, than pull|merge

Comment: @ReimerBehrends - can't see anything bad with MQ's linearity. "TTL" of MQ-patch is developer's choice - they can be strictly permanent and updateable on demand

Comment: @LazyBadger - Linearity means that you can't create branches of the full version, e.g. if you want to add a new feature to it. Transient nature refers to the fact that MQs are patches and you will have to reconcile them whenever you have conflicts. In the end, MQs are a poor man's secret branch for this purpose. They shine when it comes to history editing or to temporarily shelving experimental work, but create workflow problems for anything that's large and permanent.

Comment: @ReimerBehrends - instead of (named) branches I'll create additional patch in patchset, share in with MQCollab and join with "Full version" queue after all. MQ-patches can be merged (rather easy)with changed core after pulling Lite. Type of usage of MQ is more matter of habits, than existing real limitations (from my POV) - I **have** MQ in long-term project

Comment: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension#Merging_patches_with_new_upstream_revisions BTW

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I stumbled across this question. Now I found a solution which I'd like to share with you.

Suppose we have two devices, A and B, both having essentially the same firmware, but with certain differences which are supposed to be retained. Thus the two versions are retained in two branches - `A` and `B`.

If I make now a change at one of the versions, I can merge them over to the other one under certain conditions.

The condition is that the common precedessor (common base) must be of the "giving" branch.

In order to ensure this, you can do

```
hg debugsetparents . <other branch before the modifications>
```

After doing this, the current working set is like a merge of two branches, except that the data remains stable, i. e. "we" keep "our" stuff.

After this, you can do a "real" merge with the other branch *after* the modifications.

The result of doing so is that you get exactly the difference between the manually-created common base in the giving branch and the final state of the giving branch, resulting in exactly the modifications you want to get.